# IBM MQ correlation id length limit issue

Tags: c#, .net, queue, websphere, message-queue

I am using the .net client to send and receive IBM MQ messages.

I am setting the correlation id property under MQMessage to send and receive. I am able to send a message to the queue when the correlation id length is small(Accurately 24 characters) but giving me an error when it is more than 24.

I read the IBM documentation and found this

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/iis/9.1?topic=properties-hex-correlation-id

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/iis/9.1?topic=properties-value-correlation-id

In order to support Hexadecimal correlation ID of 48 characters i need to set 'Hex' property to true which is by default false.

But not sure how to set up Hex property.